# how do i download pywhatkit without error?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I've tried to install pywhatkit and it give me this error:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dqup4ot8\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (31 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
      sys.exit(_main())
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
      command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 105, in create_command
      module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 17, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
      from .req_install import InstallRequirement
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 10, in <module>
      import uuid
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uuid.py", line 138
      if not 0 <= time_low < 1<<32L:
                                  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dqup4ot8\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

`uuid` is part of the python standard library since [python 2.5](https://peps.python.org/pep-0356/), so it struck me as odd that it was being imported from `c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uuid.py` instead of `c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Lib\uuid.py`.

I checked and it looks very much like you have (most likely under false assumptions) downloaded and installed `uuid` through `pip` which gave you [this](https://pypi.org/project/uuid/) module, which is a very much outdated package which has long been superseeded by `uuid` in the standard library of python. It does however shadow the correct `uuid` and is not compatible with your python version (because it is more than 15 years out of date). You will need to delete it.  Try to simply do

```
pip uninstall uuid
```

If that fails, manually delete these two items:

```
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uuid-1.30.dist-info
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uuid.py
```